# Firebase returning data that does not exist. How can I fix it?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have three objects (Book, Listicle_modell and Feed_modell) and I want to retrieve in a list of objects. 
But I'm obtaining data from Firebase Database that does not exist.

My firebase structure:

```js
-userid 
 - key
   -name2: Nova Conta
   -title: The best music in the world;
   -thumbnail: url;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ9md.png)**i just have one child, why I'm getting Firebase give me three objects ? **.

In my Database I just have one child that has values that matchs Feed_modell, but I'm getting the layout from book and listicles either without having these objects (keys that match book.class and listicle) in my database as the pics show:
[image]

[image]

The problem is this: ** these two images that have no title, no thumbnail, no name, just have a views written, are being **called** but they do **not exist**, *the Test Ad is working perfectly*.

This is my Android code:

```
    dbforFeed = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("feedPosts").child(feedReceivingKey);

    dbforFeed.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Feed_modell post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Feed_modell.class);
            Book book = dataSnapshot.getValue(Book.class);
            Listicle_modell lm = dataSnapshot.getValue(Listicle_modell.class);

            feedList.addAll(Arrays.asList(post, book, new all_modell("ca-app-pub-4452407171570296~9731286762"), lm));

            recyclerViewFeedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled( DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Here is my database structure

[image]

Comment: Please add your database structure (screenshot) to see it more clearly.

Comment: Ialready  added a scrennshot of my database structure  Sir.

Comment: Where do you see data that does not exist?

Comment: In my app app layout, as I show in the emulator screenshot. I just have one child, but I'm seeing three posts (one that I have and two that I don't)

Comment: As I show in my android emulator scrennshots above, When reading my app should only appear a layout for a child that I have and an Ads Test, but I'm getting 2 more layouts as if I had more childrens in my database structure, which is not the case.

Comment: What is the type of the class of the existing object `Feed_modell`, `Book` or `Listicle_modell`?

Comment: String.class all of them Sir

Comment: You did not understand. What class of those three has this fields (Tag, UID, date, link, name2 etc)?

Comment: Ohh Sorry... Feed_modell has. Just Feed_modell has these fields

Answer (score 0):

An important practice when using a NoSQL database is to have under a node (feedPosts), objects of the same type. As I understand from your comment:

> Feed_modell has. Just Feed_modell has these fields.

The existing object is of type `Feed_modell`. As I see in your code, from the same `dataSnapshot` object you are trying to get three different objects `Feed_modell`, `Book` and `Listicle_modell`, which is not correct. A single `dataSnapshot` can be converted to a single object type. To solve this, please see the following changes:

```
List<Listicle_modell> feedList = new ArrayList<>();
//Feed_modell post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Feed_modell.class);
//Book book = dataSnapshot.getValue(Book.class);
Listicle_modell lm = dataSnapshot.getValue(Listicle_modell.class);
feedList.add(lm);
recyclerViewFeedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Make sure your adapter is also of type `Listicle_modell`.

Comment: But I can't retrieve my objects like this. I will just be able to acess one object

Comment: As I already told you, under a single node you should store a single type of objects. If you need to get other objects as well, create another node, named `books` and in this new created node add just objects of type `Book`, right?

Comment: Furthermore, your adapter cannot be of three types, only of a single type, in that case of type `Listicle_modell`.

Comment: Well... I will do what you said, thank you Alex Mamo. Your help was really good, thank you for your patience. Thank you.